# Defining the set of possible values that a variable can take

Tags: cvxpy

In CVXPY, how do I enforce the constraint that the value of a specific variable can take only a specific value from a given set of values?

eg: Value of the variable should be one out of the set P = [2, 4, 8, 9]

Comment: I think you might have to write your own branch and bound routine to solve this. You can still use cvxpy to solve the relaxation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use boolean variables and write

```
bool_vars = [Variable(bool=True) for e in P]
x = sum([v*e for e in P])
constraints = [sum(bool_vars) == 1]
```